# ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub not found error while installing capistrano as ansible playbook

Tags: wordpress, capistrano, ansible

I try to install https://github.com/roots/bedrock-ansible to get a bedrock deployment (http://roots.io/wordpress-stack/) running.

When I run "vagrant up", after some time I get the error:

```
TASK: [capistrano-setup | Setup deploy group] ********************************* 
skipping: [default]

TASK: [capistrano-setup | Setup deploy user] ********************************** 
skipping: [default]

TASK: [capistrano-setup | Adding public key to server] ************************ 
fatal: [default] => could not locate file in lookup: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

FATAL: all hosts have already failed -- aborting

PLAY RECAP ******************************************************************** 
           to retry, use: --limit @/Users/johannes/site.retry

default                    : ok=46   changed=16   unreachable=1    failed=0   

Ansible failed to complete successfully. Any error output should be
visible above. Please fix these errors and try again.
```

I do not have a clou how i can fix this. Do you have an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the role is trying to find your local public key. It should be in the location in the error message '~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub', but it's not. So either you don't have one, or you keep it in another location.

If you're not familiar with generating SSH keys you probably don't have one. I personally like the GitHub help page for this: https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys/
(you only have to perform steps 1 and 2).

If you do have SSH keys, but in a different location, the capistrano-install role in bedrock uses some variables:

```
deploy_user: deploy
deploy_keys:
  - "~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub"
```

So you can set (multiple) public key files in the `deploy_keys` list and they will be added to the `deploy_user`'s authorized keys.

All this is needed because Capistrano will use the deploy user to connect to the remote server later. http://blakesmith.me/2010/02/08/understanding-public-key-private-key-concepts.html