# Vagrant up fails due to lookup file id_rsa.pub

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, ansible

I have this problem on my machine, `vagrant up --provision` (suddenly only works with sudo prefix) hangs on the lookup for the file id_rsa.pub.

The file is created, in place, still gives me this error:

[image]

I [checked this site explaining the error](https://discourse.roots.io/t/task-fail2ban-ensure-fail2ban-is-installed/4264), no match for me

also [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27279190/ssh-id-rsa-pub-not-found-error-while-installing-capistrano-as-ansible-playboo) is not relevant

So, why i'am getting this error, even the file is created, in place & exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was due to user access rights mismatch from so many different installs over the years that i had to re-install mac os-x, after that all worked like it should be.

Vagrant was not asking for sudo, no fails during setup Virtualbox.

Everything worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

The above error is rooted in the Ansible provisioning, not vagrant specifically. You mentioned that you are running `vagrant provision` as root, which means the relative path `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` would be `/var/root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`. I would revisit why you are using sudo to run `vagrant provision` as this is incorrect.

Comment: i had to re-install os-x, now its working like it should be, still giving you an upvote for taking the effort for answering. thx